# how fetch the address bar value with '+'sign?

Tags: java

I want to fetch the address bar contents with '+'sign.

```
  http://localhost:8080/WebService/register.jsp?hdEnc=1ijga8ZMQsjlN//74b+D9g==
```

above mentioned address bar i want to fetch the whole string '1ijga8ZMQsjlN//74b+D9g==' with + sign.

using java.

Comment: What address bar?  Where are you running Java?

Comment: Did you mean *JavaScript*, not Java?

Comment: You should clarify your used technology

Comment: By the way, this query string could not interpreted as a list of parameters, otherwise == needs to be expressed in % notation

Comment: i used java so i posted in java.

Comment: In that case you need to clarify your question. Which address bare are we talking about? Is it a Java applet or are you trying to do something on the server side using JSP?

Comment: And why does `HttpServletRequest#getParameter` not solve the problem for you?

Comment: @Mathias Schwarz i dont know but getParameter not access + sign and getQuerystring method will access all the string with + sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working with servlets, take this

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29

In JSP with JSTL-taglib you could access the query string by

${pageContext.request.queryString}

Comment: Thanks For your rply stefan but i am working in jsp so how can i do?

Comment: In JSP you can get query parameter using request.getParameter(paramName). For you it will be like request.getParameter("hdEnc")

Comment: @jaxb but getParameter not fetch the '+' sign

Comment: so request.getQueryString() method fetch the string